# Grouping features with identical values in two fields and deleteing the geometry with the lowest value in the third field using QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, line, geometry, grouping, duplication

I've got a shapefile with three fields: `"X"`, `"Y"` and `"Z"` they are the geometries as well but I also have them as field values.

Every line geometry in the shapefile has a duplicate that has a different `"Z"` value so I want to delete the duplicates with the smaller `"Z"` value.

When I run delete duplicates it deletes everything with a larger `"Z"` value instead.

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't test this solution, so backup your layer please. Use the [Select by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#select-by-expression) QGIS tool with this expression:

```
minimum(
    "Z", -- find minimum z
    array($x, $y) -- group by x and y to get duplicates
) = "Z" -- true if the current z is the lower in the duplicates
```

Then toggle edit and remove selected features.

Comment: That's worked, thanks for your help

Comment: @sistema, good to hear that it worked!! If you find my answer useful, please mark it as accepted, this help people with the same question to fin this post easier. 